# Custom setRender() for BarChart give an error

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have **HorizontalBarChart** from **MPandroidchart**, I want to **rotate values** for each bar. I created class `MyBarChartRender.java` but when I put it into chartBar.setRender(), I get an **error**:

```
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                                                                 at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawDataSet(BarChartRenderer.java:136)
                                                                 at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawData(BarChartRenderer.java:80)
                                                                 at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:231)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17189)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16171)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16166)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16166)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17192)
                                                                 at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1737)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16171)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17192)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16171)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16166)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16166)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16166)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16166)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16955)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17192)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:756)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16171)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6344)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

I don't know from which array it try to read so I have no idea how to solve this problem by myself.

**MyBarChartRender.java:**

```
public class MyBarChartRender extends BarChartRenderer {

    public MyBarChartRender(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

        public void drawValue(Canvas c, IValueFormatter formatter, String value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color) {

            // super.drawValue(c, formatter, value, entry, dataSetIndex, x, y, color);

            Paint paint=super.mDrawPaint;
            paint.setTextSize(25f);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
            Utils.drawXAxisValue(c,value,x,y,paint, MPPointF.getInstance(),90);
        }}
```

**BarChart:**

```
 BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "");
                    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
                    barData.setBarWidth(1f);
                    barData.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
                    barData.setValueTextSize(9);
                    barDataSet.setColors(colors);
                    chartBar.setData(barData);
                    chartBar.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(howMany);
                    chartBar.setDescription(null);
                    chartBar.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                    chartBar.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    chartBar.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
                    chartBar.setDrawBorders(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
                    chartBar.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
                    chartBar.setScaleEnabled(false);
                    chartBar.setTouchEnabled(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
                    chartBar.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0f);
                    chartBar.setRenderer(new MyBarChartRender(chartBar,chartBar.getAnimator(),chartBar.getViewPortHandler()));
                    chartBar.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
                    chartBar.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                    chartBar.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
                    chartBar.getXAxis().setTextSize(12);
                    XAxis xAxis = chartBar.getXAxis();
                    xAxis.setLabelCount(howMany);
                    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(90);

                    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(partiesName));
                    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Before I try to use render every thing works fine.

**EDIT:**

Error problem is solved but using `MyBarChartRender.java` rotate bars and values. How can I make it to rotate only values ?

Comment: can you check if `chartBar.getAnimator()`, `chartBar.getViewPortHandler()` is not null?

Comment: @RahulKumar I checked it and they are not null

Comment: have you called `initBuffers` before calling this?

Comment: @RahulKumar No, I don't. I found some tip to solve it: Make custom render Class that extends BarChartRenderer 
Override method drawDataSet (easiest approach is to copy over drawDataSet method code from BarChartRenderer.java) 
Change occurrences of "drawRect" to "drawRoundedRect"
Set the renderer to your bar chart...
barChart.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler())); 

But I dont know how to Override the method

Comment: i mean even calling `initBuffers` will do the job

Comment: @RahulKumar can you show me on my code how to do this ? I'm try but when I call `initBuffers` I get **null**

Comment: after `super` in MyBar... constructor, place `initBuffers()`

Comment: @RahulKumar Thanks, a lot for your help, now it works but it rotate all my bars isted of only values, do you know how can I rotate only values ?

Comment: unfortunately, I came here because of Android tag and I have not worked on this library. But once you understand the code of the library, you'll get it working. :-)